# PHP/CURL. Неправильная кодировка

Tags: php, curl

Есть специальный сайт, авторизируюсь по спец ссылке, где передаются логин и хэш. Если перейти по ссылке через браузер, то нормально сайт открывается, авторизация проходит. Если сделать это через curl, то открывается страница с непонятной кодировкой.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: У меня та же проблема, но на Java...
Такие же крякозябры

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Общий случай - для начала

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING ,"");
```

на всякий случай, чтобы не вернулся закодированный ответ, очень похоже на gzip.

Далее, к примеру если твой проект в UTF-8

```
$body = curl_exec($ch);
$body = iconv('кодировка-источника', 'UTF-8', $body);
```

Если нужно автоматическое определение кодировки источника - поможет объект `DOMDocument` .

Чтобы понять что у тебя конкретно не так - нужны заголовки, которые отдал источник при твоём запросе. Включи заголовки в вывод, и прикрепи к вопросу:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот программа автоподбора кодировки.

Для счастья нужно **ПРАВИЛЬНО** , построчно получить заголовок и  отфильтровать кодировку из него(найти значение charset), для этого используем Call-back функцию(в нашем случае это HandleHeaderLine) и опцию CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, потом преобразовать в нужную нам кодировку при помощи iconv:

```
$site_charset;
    function HandleHeaderLine( $curl, $header_line ) {
        global $site_charset;//берём глобальнуюю переменую(знаю это зло но всё же)
        $pos=stripos($header_line,'charset');
        if($pos===false)
            return strlen($header_line);
        $site_charset =substr($header_line,$pos+8,-2);
        //echo $header_line ."<br> ";
        //echo "TESR".substr($header_line,$pos+8,-2)  . "<br>";
        return strlen($header_line);
    }
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, "HandleHeaderLine");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    //Ваши действия
    $out= curl_exec($curl);
    if($site_charset!="UTF-8")
        echo iconv($site_charset,"UTF-8",$out);
    curl_close($curl);
```